# html form name= php variable

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form (basically a test) that the users has to fill in.  The question nr I get from the MySQL table but I can not get the question number carried over to the answer.php file.

**form**

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $test_name=$row1['test_name'];
    $q_nr=$row1['q_nr'];
    $q_type=$row1['q_type'];
    $question=$row1['question'];
    $option1=$row1['option1'];
    $option2=$row1['option2'];
    echo "<form method='post' action='answer.php'>";
    echo "<P><strong>$q_nr $question</strong><BR>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$q_nr' value='option1'>$option1<BR>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$q_nr' value='option2'>$option2<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "</p>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Send Form'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

answer.php

```
<?php
$q_nr = $_GET['q_nr'] ;
echo $q_nr;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to get all questions and display them on the one page and then submit all answers to answer.php? In that case you could:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

echo "<form method='post' action='answer.php'>";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $test_name=$row1['test_name'];
    $q_nr=$row1['q_nr'];
    $q_type=$row1['q_type'];
    $question=$row1['question'];
    $option1=$row1['option1'];
    $option2=$row1['option2'];

    echo "<P><strong>$q_nr $question</strong><BR>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='$option1'>$option1<BR>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='$option2'>$option2<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "</p>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Send Form'>";
echo "</form>";
```

And on answer.php:

```
//Key is $q_nr and $answer is selected $option
foreach($_POST['question'] as $key => $answer) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's working, is just not sending the option they chose to answer.php but I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Is it sending anything? you can try to var_dump($_POST); in answer.php to see what did your form send.

Comment: Hi, yes it's sending the question numbers but not the answers chosen, I'll try the above.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I did the var_dum($_POST); and seems it's sending the answers, my output was:  3740array(1) { ["question"]=> array(2) { [37]=> string(7) "A) True" [40]=> string(7) "A) True" } }

Comment: Oh yes if you copied my answer.php, then it is only outputting the question number. Answer is stored in $answer variable in foreach loop.

Comment: Hi, one of my answers options is a checkbox but in answer.php it's only sending the last selected checkbox, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

First your form submission method is POST and your are retrieving in GET,

Secondly its not going to work dude, you are creating many forms in loop, It is a logic realted problem, put your FORM out of the loop and make the elelent an array like q_nr[] -------

Comment: Thank you, I took the form out of the loop but now it is only displaying 1 question from the table?  How should I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

If FORM METHOD equals POST you get the params in $_POST superglobal variable:

```
 $q_nr = $_POST['q_nr'] ;
```

Comment: Hi, I changed my answer.php (the action page) to '$q_nr = $_POST['q_nr'] ;' but its still not displaying the q_nr, should I just use 'echo "<input type='radio' name='$q_nr' value='option1'>$option1<BR>"' in the form?