# Form with radio buttons & checkboxes sending to php

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

Harmiih really helped me with my script (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510546/html-form-name-php-variable).  Basically I have a table with questions.  The form retrieves the questions from the table and then I need the selected answers to go to answer.php.  Everything is working with the radio butttons but with the check boxes it's only sending the last selected checkbox.  Can someone please help me?

**form**

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid' AND q_type = 'mr' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

echo "<form method='post' action='answer.php'>";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $test_name=$row1['test_name'];
    $q_nr=$row1['q_nr'];
    $q_type=$row1['q_type'];
    $question=$row1['question'];
    $option1=$row1['option1'];
    $option2=$row1['option2'];


    echo "<P><strong>$q_nr $question</strong><BR>";

    if ($q_type != 'mr') {

        if($option1!="") {
            echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='$option1'>$option1<BR>";
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
        if($option2!="") {
            echo "<input type='radio' name='question[$q_nr]' value='$option2'>$option2<BR>";
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
    } else {
        if($option1!="") {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr]' value='$option1'>$option1<BR>";
        } else {
            echo '';
        } 
        if($option2!="") {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='question[$q_nr]' value='$option2'>$option2<BR>";
        } else {
            echo '';
        } 
    }

    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "</p>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Send Form'>";
echo "</form>";
```

**answer.php**

```
<?php
//Key is $q_nr and $answer is selected $option
foreach($_POST['question'] as $key => $answer) {
    echo $key;
    echo $answer;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as name:

```
name="question[$q_nr][]"
```

This will make sure you return an array containing all values of the selected checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you, JNDPNT's answer helped me, in my form I used:

    name='question[$q_nr][]'

and in my answer.php:

    foreach($_POST['question'] as $key => $answer) {
    echo $answer[0];
    echo $answer[1];
    }

Comment: Btw you don't have to echo all checkbox answers manually because you can't tell how many checkboxes user will select. One example how you could do it. [link](http://pastebin.com/vjS44ZMi)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have different `name` values in checkboxes.

For example  `name='question1[$q_nr]'` and `name='question2[$q_nr]'`. The same name works only with grouping elements witch radio buttons are.

Or passing them as arrays:

`name='question[$q_nr][1]'` and `name='question[$q_nr][2]'`